# Laravel Update Record using Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

I working on laravel project and trying to update record using query builder but it not working , 
this is the function where I trying to edit the record in it

```
public function editchecksave(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;
    $username = $request->username;
    $attribute = $request->attribute;
    $value = $request->value;
    $op = $request->op;

    $result = DB::update('update radcheck set username = "?" , 
        attribute="?",value="?" ,op="?" where id = ?', 
        [$username,$attribute,$value,$op,$id]
    );

    if ($result)
    {
        return response()->json([ 'msg' => 'Updated Successfully' . $username]);
    }

    return response()->json([ 'msg' => 'Not Updated Successfully'. $value]);
}
```

this is the route

```
 Route::get( 'radcheckedit', 'radcheckController@editchecksave' );
```

when I do not change the first element in the update query it not updated but when I change the first element it updated successfully .in other words (when I change the value of username it updated successfully and when I do not change the username not updated , when I put the attribute first element in the query it must change the value of it to make update so user must change the first value of query and it not good because user may be doesn't want to edit this element)

it give me the Message Not updated successfully

Comment: `DB::update` isn't supposed to be used the way you're using it here, I'm not sure if it does accept a raw query, if it does you'd have to do something like `DB::update(DB::raw('query here'));` You should probably take a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#updates) for the query builder based on updates.

Comment: not worked thank you

Comment: Consult with @Jerodev answer below, this your best explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You shouldn't put a raw query in the [`update`](https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_update) function, it requires an array of to-update values. You can write your query using the build-in querybuilder:

```
$result = DB::table('radcheck')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->update([
        'username' => $username,
        'attribute' => $attribute,
        'value' => $value,
        'op' => $op
    ]);
```

Or even better without having to fetch the variables from the request manually:

```
$result = DB::table('radcheck')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->update($request->only(['username', 'attribute', 'value', 'op']));
```

This will also make the code more readable.

Comment: thank you for reply but it returned {"msg":"Not Updated Successfully"} message  I don't know where is the wrong

Comment: Are you sure that that table has these columns and that there are no restrictions preventing you from updating this data?

Comment: yes I found the error that when I not change the username it not updated and when I change the username it updated successfully so where is my wrong ?

Comment: @Muh I think if you send the same data to update the record in the database doesn't "execute" the query because the values are the same (it's an optimization), so if you want to update always, you must send a field like "updated_at", then your verification will work, to do it add something like 'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now() to your query.